# IDbTransaction.Commit returns before transaction is complete

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, ddl

I have a server which (rarely) dynamically creates database rows to accommodate the data model the user configures. During startup the server may have to create about a thousand rows as well as multiple inserts into existing tables.

When all this is done, it commits the transaction and sends out notifications about the new data model to anyone who might be listening. The issue is, that transaction.Commit() appears to return before the database has actually finished making the changes, so if a client makes a request to the server after it has sent out the notifications, the client may get an empty result. My assumption was that waiting for transaction.Commit() would ensure that the transaction was all done and committed.

The reason why the client gets an empty result is that when not doing DDL operations the database is using snapshot isolation, so clearly the snapshot is taken before the DDL operation has completed (but well after transaction.commit has returned)

The order of operations is:

1. Start transaction
2. Do thousands of operations in database (DDL)
3. Commit transaction
4. Send notifications about changes
5. Client requests data (Snapshot isolation)
6. No data (state before transaction) is returned to client.

Why does transaction.Commit() finish before the transaction has finished committing? How can I make the server wait for the transaction to be completely finished before proceeding to send out the notifications?

Edit: Clarity.

Comment: Maybe you have an outer transaction going on at the same time? Then your Commit doesn't actually apply changes until that outer transaction commits.

Comment: This is of course a possibility (It's a pretty mature framework so not super easy to navigate) but I am fairly certain it is not the case. I will investigate though - as I wrote below, though, after I commit I close the connection, so a parent transaction can hardly block. 

If we assume it is not the case, this only seems to happen when DDL is involved. Normal database updates appear to be completely wrapped up after Commit finishes.

Comment: When you say DDL, do you mean CREATE statements? DDL will use schema modification locks and block other sessions regardless of transaction isolation level so perhaps you mean DML (inserts). I suggest you run a trace to verify the sequence of transactions. The symptoms suggest the client request (#5) is done in a snapshot transaction that started before step #1.

Comment: I mean DDL - not on the table I read from though. I add columns to some tables, and rows to others for book keeping in a single transaction. @Evk I do have an outer TransactionScope, however supressing it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Evk - It was indeed the outer TransactionScope causing trouble! Make it a proper answer and you'll get a proper ceremony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in comments, one possible reason for this is pending outer transaction. As stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When used in nested transactions, commits of the inner transactions
> don't free resources or make their modifications permanent. The data
> modifications are made permanent and resources freed only when the
> outer transaction is committed. Each COMMIT TRANSACTION issued when
> @@TRANCOUNT is greater than one simply decrements @@TRANCOUNT by 1.
> When @@TRANCOUNT is finally decremented to 0, the entire outer
> transaction is committed. Because transaction_name is ignored by the
> Database Engine, issuing a COMMIT TRANSACTION referencing the name of
> an outer transaction when there are outstanding inner transactions
> only decrements @@TRANCOUNT by 1.

So despite `Commit()` is executed successfully, if outer transaction is present - no changes will be persisted to database until that outer transaction commits too.

Comment: Note that the outer transaction can be ignored by adding Enlist=False to the SQL connection string.

Answer (score 1):

This is the natural behaviour of 'Snapshot Isolation'. Check this link:
https://www.sqlshack.com/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server/

"When another session reads the same data, the committed version of the data as of the time the reading transaction began is returned."

You have to kill the session in order to other transcation can read it. Or change it to 'Read Committed'.

Comment: I get that snapshot isolation will read the state of the latest completed transaction. 

My problem is that the DDL transaction isn't completed when I expect it to be, so I start sending notifications too early - so the client request (which is snapshot isolation) reads the wrong data. My issue lies with the write (And not waiting for it to finish), not the read.

Comment: Because, in snapshot isolation current version of row is copied to tempDb. If anyone wants to read it, database will return old data. It does so to prevent locking. My advice is try to change isolation level to committed which locks uncommitted rows. But in ms sql server, there is a way to overcome this, add 'with(nolock)' end of select statement.

Comment: Actually there is no 'too early' stitution. You will read old data unless you end your session.

Comment: The server commits the transaction. Then it closes the connection to the database. Then it sends out notifications. Then the client makes a request to the server, which creates a new session (snapshot isolation) and reads the data. If I read committed locks would ensure that the latter read waited. I do need to use snapshot isolation though. My issue is, that IDbTransaction.Commit returns before that data has been fully committed.

Comment: There is nothing in that quote indicating you will read the same data for the whole session. "version of the data as of the time the reading transaction began is returned" - not when session started.